# Java Add Loop with ADT's

Tags: java

I'm using a JUnit Test Case to test the methods I've created for a rational fractions ADT. I'm currently testing the `add()` method. I have an ArrayList of fractions 1/2, 2/3, 3/4,... 9/10 which I've created using a for loop. I then created a Rational fraction `fsum` and initialized it to the value in `fractions.get(0);`. I then made a for loop to add each other value in the ArrayList to the Rational fraction `fsum`. After I test the assertion, everything turns out correct, however this doesn't seem to be the most efficient way to add up all the fractions in the `fractions` ArrayList. Is there another easier way to accomplish the same thing? Here is a bit of code for reference:

```
ArrayList<Rational> fractions = new ArrayList<Rational>();
for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
  fractions.add(new RationalC(i, i+1));
}    
Rational sum = new RationalC(17819,2520);    
Rational fsum = fractions.get(0);    
for(int j=1; j<9; j++){
  fsum = fsum.add(fractions.get(j));
}    
assertTrue("Sum of 1/2,2/3,...9/10", fsum.compareTo(sum) == 0);
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: _this doesn't seem to be the most efficient way_ Why do you think not?

Comment: Well for example, creating a separate variable with the value of the first index and adding values to that seems unnecessary to me. I'm new to Java so I'm only just getting used to the conventions, but I was wondering if there was a way to just loop through adding `fractions.get(0).add(fractions.get(1)).add(fractions.get(2))...` etc in one go? Or something along those lines. I can't help but feel like my way is messy

Comment: You can create a method that does it, but, behind the scene, what you currently have is what it will be doing.